# how to change the default project directory in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ankhsvn, defaults

My home directory is located on a rediculously slow network drive. I don't want visual studio to store my files there. It is sluggish, and automaticaly storing auto-restore data freezes visual studio for several seconds.

I have Ankh SVN integration, so whenever I open a project from SVN, it stores it on my sluggish default location. Is there a way to change the default location, so I don't have to manually move the projects to my local drive after checking them out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In vs 2005 it's in Tools->options->projects and solutions->general.

Comment: It turned out to be Tools->Options: Projects and Solutions->General